# Sound is not playing on collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a Game with Unity and now i want to implement a sound effect whenever the projectile hits an object. Somehow there is no sound playing. Here is the Code:

```
AudioSource sound;

void Start()
{
    ...
    sound = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    ...
}

void Destroy()
{
    sound.Play();
}
```

Comment: Are you attaching this script to your AudioSource Component gameObject?

Comment: yes i did. The gameObject has a AudioSource

Comment: Then check if your function ```Destroy()``` is getting called or not. Please check if your gameObject remains active or is destroyed, you have not mentioned this either in your question.

Comment: Maybe as soon as you start your sound, the GameObject who owns the AudioSource is destroyed and the sound stops playing straight away. You can create a new GameObject, attach an AudioSource to it, play the sound in the new GameObject and program it to be destroyed right after.

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown if Destroy() function is called or not. Please add a `Debug.Log("Called")` inside your Destroy() function and test it. If it is getting called, it could be related to the volume of the system or if the Audio component is in mute. Please check these initial things.
If it is not called then learn the difference between GetComponents.

When you attach the script to your gameobject that contains AudioComponent, write it this way:

```
private AudioSource sound;

void Start()
{
   
       sound = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
       sound.Play(); 
       
}
```

When you attach the script to a different gameObject and would like to reference the Audio gameObject to this script, write it this way:

```
public AudioSource sound;

void Start()
{
   
       sound.GetComponent<AudioSource>(); //this is optional
       sound.Play(); 
       
}
```

Don't forget to add it as reference (Drag & Drop Audio component's GameObject) in the second solution.

Comment: I don't think you even have to call `GetComponent` in the second example as `sound` IS the `AudioSource`.

Comment: @Iggy yes you are right. Was just showing the difference between the two. It is just optional. I add it in my scripts since its a habit now. :D

Comment: Do you really mean `sound.GetComponent<AudioSource>();` ?